# Functional component is not rerendering after state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to ask why my component is not rerendering after my state is changed and I need to refresh it (switch between routes) to see changes. Well, the interesting fact is that the first time when I click the delete button page (component) does not rerender but after I switch routes and come back the item is deleted and when I try to delete other items, it gets deleted instantly not like the first time.

This is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ApiFactory from '../mock';
import Editor from '../Editor';
import ProductCard from '../components/product-card/product-card';
import ProductEdit from '../components/product-edit/product-edit';

export default function Admin() {
  const [items, setItems]= useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();

  }, [items]);

  function getProducts() {
    ApiFactory.getInstance().get('/api/products')
      .then((res) => {
        if(res.status == 200) {
          setItems(res.data);     
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error)}) 
  }

  function handleDelete (productId) {
    ApiFactory.getInstance().delete(`/api/products/${productId}`)
     .then(()=> getProducts()
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
     {
      items.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item.id)
        return <>
          <div key={index}>
            <ProductCard product={item}></ProductCard>
            <button onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>Delete</button>
          </div>
          </>
      }) 
    }
    </>
  );
}
```

I am quite new in React can anybody explain why it happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: You probably should remove the item manually in the array instead of fetching the whole products list again.

Comment: Did it, but not working with `items.slice(items.indexOf(x=>x.id == productId),1);`

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because of how you have useEffect set up.

1. change the useEffect to only make the GET API call once (on initial load):

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       getProducts();

     }, []); // remove the dependency here. You may have made an infinite        loop here.

     const getProducts = () => {
       ApiFactory.getInstance().get('/api/products')
         .then((res) => {
           if(res.status == 200) {
             setItems(res.data);    
           }
         })
         .catch((error) => { console.log(error)}) 
     }
   ```

If you confirmed that the API call is handling your errors / successes (are you getting non 200 status codes ? those may not be handled)

2. Add error catching to handleDelete to make sure this call works.

   ```
   const handleDelete = (productId) => {
       ApiFactory.getInstance().delete(`/api/products/${productId}`)
       .then(getProducts())
       ).catch((error) => { console.log(error)}) 
   }
   ```

You may additionally do as another user suggested and move even more logic away from the API calls (not required though) to have state locally and not re-fetch data from the API.